# How to include and position JS widget from another JS function

Tags: javascript, widget

I am working on a demo website as a novice. As described in the sample code given below, I am using a third party JS widget (Part 1) that I want to display when a condition (Part 3.1) is met.

```
<!-- PART 1: JS Widget -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/def.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Something({
     id1  :  "a1",
     id2  :  "b1"
  });
</script>

<!-- PART 2: Button that triggers JS function -->
<input id="clickme" type="button" value="Find Results"     onclick="dofunction2();"/>

<!-- PART 3: JS function -->
function dofunction2(){

$(function(){

    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "";
    var url="http://rest-api/location/manchester";

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

        for (var i=0; i < data.listings.length; i++) {
            text = text + "<b>" +  data.listings[i].name + "</b></br>";
            text = text + "Address: " + data.listings[i].address + "</br>"; 

            <!-- PART 3.1: Condition that decides whether to display widget or not -->
            if(data.listings[i].showScript == null) {

                //display widget here
            }
            else {
                //dont display widget
            }           
        }
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
    });
});
```

};

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: If you want to change the website code depending on the url query string it could be useful to write serverside scripts.